# When I add a new subdirectory in CMake, the bug occurs

Tags: c++, cmake, glfw

I have project that builds with CMake.
Here is project hierarchy:

```
Project
   Dependencies
      glfw
   Source
      CMakeList.txt
      main.cpp
   CMakeList.txt
```

Then I try to add GLFW to my project and my CMakeList file looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

# Enable Hot Reload for MSVC compilers if supported.
if (POLICY CMP0141)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0141 NEW)
set(CMAKE_MSVC_DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT "$<IF:$<AND:$<C_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>,$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>>,$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:EditAndContinue>,$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:ProgramDatabase>>")
endif()

project( Project )

# Include sub - projects.

set(GLFW_BUILD_DOCS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

set(MAIN "Source/main.cpp")

add_subdirectory("Dependencies/glfw")

add_executable( Project ${MAIN} )

target_link_libraries( Project glfw )
```

With the version of the file above, everything works fine.

When I add this line 'add_subdirectory("Source")`' to CMakeList, an error occurs in the main.cpp that the file cannot be found: 'GLFW/glfw3.h'. I want to understand why the error occurs.

main.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main()
{
    //glewExperimental = true; // Needed for core profile
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n");
        return -1;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
CMakeList.txt in Source directory:

```
add_executable (CMakeTarget "Game Engine.cpp" )

if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_GREATER 3.12)
  set_property(TARGET CMakeTarget PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 20)
endif()
```

Comment: Why should it be able to find the file? Is there a GLFW/glfw3.h installed in your compiler?

Comment: Yes, it is located at Dependencies folder. Plus, without adding a subdirectory ("Source") everything works.

Comment: and why would the compiler look there?

Comment: Where did you get Dependencies/glfw/CMakeLists.txt from?

Comment: @ecatmur I downloaded GLFW source package from the official site

Comment: This seems like you setup the folders incorrectly. Possibly you have GLFW in your project folders and not built and installed in a separate location.

Comment: @user253751 Because I specified in the CMake file that GLFW should be included in the project.

Comment: add_subdirectory tells CMake that it should open Dependencies/glfw/CMakeLists.txt and run the code there. It has nothing to do with where the compiler finds header files.

Comment: What are the contents of Source/CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: @drescherjm The compiler can find GLFW, but when I add such a line to CMakeList : add_subdirectory("Source"), then error occurs.

Comment: "When I add this line 'add_subdirectory("Source")'" - Where exactly in your `CMakeLists.txt` you have added this line?

Comment: @Tsyvarev After the 'project( Project ) line

Comment: @ecatmur I have edited the question and added the contents of the file.

Comment: You current question post has several inconsistences. In `Source/CMakeLists.txt` you have the line `add_executable (CMakeTarget "Game Engine.cpp" )`. but there is no `Source/Game Engine.cpp` file on your scheme. You tell that "an error occurs in the main.cpp", but that source is part of your `Project` target, not of the `CMakeTarget` one. Please, read what [mcve] is and edit the question post to include your **exact code** and **exact error message** you got ("... that the file cannot be found ..." is not the error message, it is *description* of the error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you link `Project` to glfw but do not link `CMakeTarget` (strange name, btw) to glfw.

You need to add the line:

```
target_link_libraries( CMakeTarget glfw )
```

This is because CMake uses link libraries to determine how to set up include paths for the compiler as well as for linking. Specifically, it works because glfw has a PUBLIC `target_include_directories` here: https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/9a87635686c7fcb63ca63149c5b179b85a53a725/src/CMakeLists.txt#L140